# How do I access the row index in an agate Formula?

Tags: python, row

Using Python's tabular data library [agate](https://github.com/wireservice/agate) I want to define a compute `Formula`, which accesses the *row index*. I tried

```
agate.Formula(agate.Text(), lambda r: r.index())
```

but this doesn't work, because the `Row` object does not provide a (row) index (unlike the Column object!). Is there a way to access the row index *inside* the formula?

(I need this in order to create a new column with values unique for each row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my research I concluded, that theer is no way to access the row number in the function of a standard `Formula`. (Of course I'm happy to be proven wrong!)

However in order to achieve what's asked in the question I can subclass `Formula`, change the signature of the called function add the row number as parameter in:

```
class EnumeratedFormula(agate.Formula):
    """
    An agate formula which provides a row index to its compute function
    The function used has now the signature f(i,r)
    """
    def run(self, table):
        new_column = []

        for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
            v = self._func(i,row)

            if self._cast:
                v = self._data_type.cast(v)

            new_column.append(v)

        return new_column
```

With this I can write a compute expression which creates a new column with unique values unique for each row:

```
EnumeratedFormula(agate.Text(), lambda i, r: str(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody needs something similar with awareness of column inside of the function, I have modified @halloleo's code to this:

```
class FormulaWithColumn(agate.Formula):
    """
    An agate formula which can be constructed with column as additional parameter
    Constructor has now column parameter
    The function used has now the signature f(i,r)
    """

    def __init__(self, data_type, func, column, cast=True):
        self._data_type = data_type
        self._func = func
        self._column = column
        self._cast = cast

    def run(self, table):
        new_column = []

        for row in table.rows:
            v = self._func(self._column, row)

            if self._cast:
                v = self._data_type.cast(v)

            new_column.append(v)

        return new_column
```

For example, to modify several columns with the same function in a loop:

```
for i in columns_to_modify:
    table = table.compute([(table.columns[i].name, FormulaWithColumn(agate.Text(),
                            myfunction, i))], replace=True)
```

Thanks @halloleo for the groundwork

Answer (score -1):

This is from the function `__doc__`:

Must return a valid value for the specified data type. :param cast: If :code:`True`, each return value will be cast to the specified\n        :code:`data_type` to ensure it is valid.

This is from the offitial tutorial:

```
number_type = agate.Number()

def five_year_total(row):
    columns = ('2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013')

    return sum(tuple(row[c] for c in columns)]

formula = agate.Formula(number_type, five_year_total)

new_table = table.compute([
    ('five_year_total', formula)
])
```

Judging by these two, I would say that your datatype is wrong, the `index()` function returns an object type `int` yours is `text()`.
Try using the one from the docks `agate.Number()`.
The tutorials i used is http://agate.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.0/cookbook/excel.html#simple-formulas

Comment: The (output) data type of the formula is *not* the issue. As mentioned in the question my code line is not valid, because `r` has no row index, but this exactly my question: How do I access the row index *inside* the formula? Your answer doesn't address this at all.

Comment: I will update the answer. In the meantime i started useing the library.